sharpe ratio, convert into convex function, not understand that constraint,
I am reading about tranforming sharpe ratio into convex problem
After some following, its converted into min xTxy s.t. (u-rf e)x = 1
X=x+/k+

X+ = x/(u-rf e)x
K+ = 1/ (u-rf e)T x


In the book, it mention adding the normalizing constraint (u-rf)x = 1 does not affect the equation
I understand that f(x) is same as f(kx)
However, i get some questions here.
Why (u-rf)x = 1 can confirm its maximum  sharpe ratio ?
So why this constraint

This is a really messy question. Formulae not written in Latex. Sentences not clearly written out. A pasted image of a large block of text. I would be surprised if someone takes this up to answer. Perhaps some editing might help...

The page 62 you reproduce is found in Optimization in Finance by Reha Tutuncu, Research Report B-392, August 2003 here https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6a2f617a8e3a13a618b2e0b0aacbd3d752db744f but your specific question I was not able to understand

Its mentioned adding the normalizing constraint. So my question is why to add this constraint!

Sorry i am typing on phone

Please resubmit from computer with latex formulae if possible, and clarify question.

Why we choose to add this constraint  (u-rf)x = 1 , i do not need understand here, and why this constraint can make sure its maximum sharpe ratio

Also if my objective function is transformed into min xT C x, then this objective function us is same as minimum mean variance as min xT C x , s.t /sum x =1 ，so in max sharpe ratio , we reformulated same as min xT C x  ,but constraint change from u-rf > R    to (u-rf e)Tx = 1

@nbbo2
As you follow through the derivation, you'll note that y=λ⋅x
. This transformation was created to remove the numerator from the main optimization problem, and reframe it as a boundary condition (μT−1T)⋅y=1
I read about that article. So why we choose that boundary condition (μT−1T)⋅y=1 ? this seem not answered
.

After reading about A Signal Processing Perspective on Financial Engineering.
I am trying to answer my question. But I am not sure that if I am correct or not. and show my question again.
I would like to ask why we add this (µ − rf1) = 1 constraint.
min xT Σx
subject to xT
(µ − rf1) = 1,
xT 1 > 0.

First, we do homogenizing x = kx, as f(x) = f(kx), so the objective function becomes wT Σw
x = x+ / k+
x+ = x / (µ − rf1)
k+ = 1 / (µ − rf1)

this paramater given in max, so in min k become (µ − rf1)
after x = x+ / k+, it will be same as x
as x = k+x+
as we scale  constraint wT 1 = 1 can be relaxed to wT 1 > 0 so we can assume one arbitrarily set as wT(µ − rf1) = 1
k = (µ − rf1) `in min that` wT(µ − rf1) = 1 


Again this is confusing. By your own admission you do not know if this is an answer to your question or an addition to it. It will be difficult for anyone to follow along.
